# Understanding derivation of ADMM update rule for graphical lasso optimization by solving quadratic matrix equation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-equations, lagrange-multiplier, sparsity

I'm trying to understand the derivation of an ADMM update rule in some convex optimization lecture notes by Emmanuel Candes [1]. In the course of the solution (on page 25-4 and 25-5), it is required to solve the following optimization problem (which comes from the augmented Lagrangian):
$$
X_k = \text{arg min}_{X} \mathcal{L}_{\mu}(X, Y_{k-1}, Z_{k-1}) = \text{arg min}_{X \succeq 0} \Big \{
-\text{log det}X + \frac{\mu}{2} || X + (Z_{k-1} - Y_{k-1} + \frac{1}{\mu}C) ||^2_F \Big \}.
$$
where $C$ is a fixed symmetric and positive semidefinite covariance matrix, $Z_{k-1}$ is a Lagrange multiplier variable, $Y_{k-1}$ is the ADMM "dummy variable" for $X$, and $\mu$ is the penalty parameter (see the lecture notes on page 25-4 for more details). Note that we want $X \succeq 0$. First, let
$$
\tilde{C}_{k-1} = X_{k-1}- Y_{k-1} - \frac{1}{\mu} C
$$
We want to set the gradient of the Lagrangian to zero to solve for $X_k$, which means that we want to solve
$$
\nabla_X \mathcal{L}_{\mu} = -X^{-1} + \mu X -\mu \tilde{C}_{k-1} = 0
$$
which is equivalent to solving
$$
0 = X^2 - \tilde{C}_{k-1}X - \frac{1}{\mu} I
$$

Candes says on page 25-4 at the top that if the eigendecomposition of $C_{k-1}$ is $U \Lambda U^{-1}$ with $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\{\lambda_i\})$ [2], then the solution is $X^* = \mathcal{F}_{\mu}(\tilde{C}_{k-1}) = U \mathcal{F}_{\mu}(\Lambda) U^{-1} $ where
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\mu}(\Lambda) = \frac{1}{2}\text{diag} \Big ( \Big \{
\lambda_i + \sqrt{\lambda_i^2 + 4/\mu}
\Big ) \Big \}
$$
From this he concludes that the update rule is
$$
X_k = \mathcal{F}_{\mu}(\tilde{C}_{k-1}) = \mathcal{F}_{\mu}(Z_{k-1} - Y_{k-1} + \frac{1}{\mu}C).
$$

I can kind of guess at where the $\sqrt{\lambda_i^2 + 4/\mu}$ term comes from, as a quadratic matrix equation of the type $AX^2+BX+K=0$ (under some conditions) is solved by $X = (-B \pm Q)/2$ where $Q = PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$ and $PDP^{-1}$ is the eigendecomposition of the discriminant $B^2-4AK$. And here, our $B^2-4AK$ is $\tilde{C}_{k-1}^2+(4/\mu)I$. But the equation for the eigenvalues seems to assume that our $B^2-4AK$ is $C^2+(4/\mu)I$, as I believe that $C^2+(4/\mu)I$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i^2 + 4/\mu$. And where does the first $\lambda_i$ in the sum (to the left of the square root) come from? At this point I'm kind of confused and hoping for some help.

Apologies if the solution is immediately obvious, I haven't taken an advanced course in linear algebra or optimization yet.

[1] https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/math301/Lectures/ADMM.pdf

[2] Note that there seems to be a typo in the notes here: where it is stated that "$\tilde{C}_{k-1} = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ is the eigendecomposition of $C_{k-1}$", I assume the scribe meant to write that $C_{k-1} = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ is the eigendecomposition of $C_{k-1}$. At least I hope! Perhaps this is the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is late, but I came across this question when reading the same notes and hopefully this will help someone.

You are correct that there is a typo in the notes, but I think the typo is that "... is the eigenvalue decomposition of $C_{k-1}$ with $\lambda_i \geq 0$" should read "is the eigenvalue decomposition of $\tilde C_{k-1}$", with no claim on the sign of $\lambda_i$. Below, I provide justification.

We are solving $-X^{-1} + \mu X - \mu \tilde C_{k-1} = 0$, with $\tilde C_{k-1} = -Z_{k-1}+Y_{k-1}-1/\mu \cdot C$, and we want to find a positive definite solution for $X$. In the notes, a positive semidefinite solution is sought, but the below procedure will in fact give a positive definite solution.

We begin by writing $\tilde C_{k-1} = U \Lambda U^T$ as suggested in the notes. Assume for the moment that there exists a solution of the form $X = UDU^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements. In this case, the above equation becomes $U(-D+\mu D-\mu \Lambda)U^T = 0$, which reduces to $-D+\mu D-\mu \Lambda=0$. Now, $D$ and $\Lambda$ are diagonal matrices, so this equation further reduces to $-d_i^{-1}+\mu d_i - \mu \lambda_i=0$ for all $i$, where $D = {\rm diag}(\{d_i\})$ and $\Lambda = {\rm diag}(\{ \lambda_i\})$. We can equivalently solve $d_i^2-\lambda_i d_i - 1/\mu = 0$, which gives $d_i = 1/2 \cdot (\lambda_i + \sqrt{\lambda_i^2+4/\mu})$ since we want $d_i>0$. Note that $d_i$ is positive even if $\lambda_i$ is negative, so we don't need $\tilde C_{k-1}$ to have nonnegative eigenvalues.

Now, working backwards, we see that $X = UDU^T$, with $D = {\rm diag}(\{d_i\})$ as described above, will give us a positive definite solution of $-X^{-1}+\mu X-\mu \tilde C_{k-1}=0$. This is the ADMM update for $X_k$.

Comment: Wow, I had almost lost hope that this question would be answered! Thank you very much for explaining this!